# Subgroup structure description

Tags: group-theory, classical-groups

I've been reading a paper on group theory, and have come across this description of a subgroup of the special linear group:

Let $G=SL(d,q)$  and $H< G$ with $H \cong (SL(k,q) \times SL(d-k,q)).(q-1)$

I understand that $(SL(k,q) \times SL(d-k,q))$ is the direct product but what operation does the $.$ represent? Does the $(q-1)$ represent $C_{q-1}$ or some other group?

Comment: This is called ATLAS notation for specifying the structure of a group. It means that $H$ has a normal subgroup $N$  isomorphic to ${\rm SL}(k,q) \times {\rm SL}(d-k,q)$ and $H/N \cong C_{q-1}$.